# Generate array of number pairs from 2 numpy vectors

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, combinations

Is there an easy way in Numpy to generate an array of number pairs from 2 1D numpy arrays (vectors) without looping?

input:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
```

output:

```
c = [(1,4), (1,5), (1,6), (2,4), (3,5), (2,6), (3,4), (3,5), (3,6)]
```

I wondering if there is a function that does something similar to this:

```
c = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(b)):
        c.append((a[i], b[j]))
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for this:

```
from itertools import product

c = list(product(a, b))
```

This gives:

```
c == [(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Comment: I will accept this answer, since it is valid, however I got away with it using a simple list comprehension: `c = [(i, j) for i in a for j in b]`

Comment: How do you refer to each coordinate of an element in c?

Comment: For anyone in the future you can do something such as: `ordered_pairs = np.column_stack((a, b))`...returns `[[1 4][2 5][3 6]]` for ops question.  @Subzero-273K - to answer you, you can access ordered each element in the ordered pair using: `ordered_pairs[0, 0]` which will result in 1 being  returned.  If you'd like to select the second number in each element you can use `[:, 1]`

Comment: I'd love to see a solution that stays within numpy to avoid the overhead of Python loops. Broadcasting, fancy indexing, vectorizing, etc.

Comment: i have a slightly diff problem but this solution can help. i want to generate all pairs out of a single array. Eg. x=[1, 2, 3] will give [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3] and i could use product(x, x). Is there an option to suppress the "self" such as [1, 1]?